# Sails.js - extend req prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I want to add some methods to `req` object prototype, so I can use those methods in every controller later on.

I've tried to do it in `config/bootstrap.js` like:

```
require('http').ClientRequest.prototype.permit = function(){
    console.log( this.params.all() );
};
```

But I dont have access to this method in `req` object of any controller action. What is the way to extend `request` or `response` objects of Sails?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer*: I'm new to sails, but I was able to a achieve what I think you were looking to do with the following.

One possible way would be to add a `hook` in the file format:

`api -> hooks -> request -> index.js`

Where index.js looks like:

```
module.exports = function request(sails) {

  function permit() {
    console.log(this.headers);
  }

  return {
    initialize: function(cb){

      sails.on('router:route', function(requestState) {
        requestState.req['permit'] = permit;
      });

      return cb();
    }
  }

};
```

For more details on sails hooks:

Project Hooks: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/hooks/project-hooks
Specification: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/hooks/hook-specification